# TypeScript - Import JSON file and assign to variable declared with an interface

Tags: json, typescript, typescript2.0

I have the following JSON file (test.json):

```
{"test":[
    {"file": "f1.txt", "nr":3},
    {"file": "f4.txt", "nr":4},
    {"file": "f7.txt", "nr":7}
]}
```

I defined an interface for this JSON structure in TypeScript:

```
export interface IJsonFiles {
    test: (FileEntity)[];
}

interface FileEntity{
    file: string;
    nr: number;
}
```

To make the import statement work in TS I had to create a json.d.ts file with the following content:

```
declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

Then I import test.json into my code as follows:

```
import * as b from '../../assets/test.json';
let files: IJsonFiles;
files = b;
```

This results in the following error:

```
TS2322: Type 'typeof import("*.json")' is not assignable to type 'IJsonFiles'.  Property 'test' is missing in type 'typeof import("*.json")'.
```

Can anybody help?
Essentially, what I am trying to achieve is:

I want to import JSON files from the file system (don't want to use require!) and I would like to have the JSON structure defined in TS (no implicit any...).

Answer (score 12):

This is how I import JSON and add type definitions to it on Node v10.16.0 and TypeScript v3.6.3.

## venues.json

```
[
  {
    "id": "c29e3ee4b23342db8afdab4c826ab478",
    "name": "Example",
    "hostnames": [
      "example.com"
    ],
    "shortcode": "example",
    "lickstatsUrl": "https://theregs.co/example",
    "pin": "1234"
  },
  ...
]
```

## index.ts

```js
import _venues from './venues.json';

interface Venue {
  id: string;
  hostnames: string[];
  shortcode: string;
  lickstatsUrl: string;
  pin: string;
}

const venues = _venues as Venue[];
```

Comment: Isn't there a prettier way as of 2022?

Answer (score 7):

Typescript 2.9 includes support for well-typed JSON importing out of the box. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/05/31/announcing-typescript-2-9/#json-imports

Edit. You could also just cast your `b` variable as `IJsonFiles` type.

```
import * as b from '../../assets/test.json';
let files: IJsonFiles = <IJsonFiles> b;
```

Comment: I did as you suggested which gives me: resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct. However import b = require('../../assets/test.json'); works. I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 3):

You can just declare new object with interface. In your case it will be the next:

```
import venuesRaw from './venues.json';

interface IVenue {
  id: string;
  hostnames: string[];
  shortcode: string;
  lickstatsUrl: string;
  pin: string;
}

const venues: Venue = venuesRaw;
```